# IntelliJ - Maven unable to install local jar file pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

I have a jar file in my source code. I'm trying to use in my project using IntelliJ IDE

in my pom.xml under dependencies I defined:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>custom_logger</groupId>
  <artifactId>custom_logger</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/custom_logger.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I ran mvn clean, mvn install and mvn package, but I can't run the project because my custom_logger.js never gets added to the external libraries. The IDE cannot resolve the imports.

Comment: That's expected for `system` scope. It's like `provided`. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: ahhhh. thank you very much... now it makes sense. I just to add it under project libraries in my IDE. I was thinking maven would automatically add it from the specified path.